# mod_alias redirect tips

Tags: regex, mod-alias

all. I search the sites but can not find my answer, so I post it.

I want to redirect url like this

example.com/css/....  ====>  example.com/templates/css/...

example.com/path/css/....  ====>  example.com/path/templates/css/...

I tired lots regular, not I wish. such as

```
RedirectMatch (.*)/css/(.*)\.css  $1/templates/css/$2.css
```

I think the last regular maybe right. but need set regular to lazy-mode. I find the apache document about mod_alias and mod_rewrite, haven't found talk about this tips.

need help. thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok,I check it out , and I leaned reglar assert features XD.

```
(^(t(?!emplates)|[^t])*?)/(css|js)/(.*)\.(css|js)$ $1/templates/$3/$4.$5
```

this works very well for me . hope can help some people.

Answer (score 0):

You get lazy match by adding `?` after `*`, like this:

```
(.*?)/css/(.*?)\.css
```

The `*` then tries to match as little as possible. This should transform the urls in your example as you expect.

By the way: Apache mod_rewrite is [Perl compatible regular expression with some additions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: this regular is right. but will cause loops for this url css ==> templates/css . 
I am thinking it.